# Как записать строку ввода во Free Pascal больше чем 255 символов?

Tags: строки, char, freepascal, ввод

Помогите придумать, как записывать строку ввода в паскале более `255` символов. Ведь, когда зажимаешь одну кнопку и ждешь пока напишутся все символы, их получатся всего 255 и больше не пишутся они.

Пример: `1111111111111...1`(`255` единиц), `256` единиц не получается записать.

Comment: Давайте попробуем взглянуть на проблему чуть шире. Для чего вам больше 255 символов в строке ввода?

Comment: Чтобы обрабатывать числа с количеством цифр больше 1000 для вычислений.

Comment: Пример: 444..4(2222 раза четверка) умножить на 555..5(5000 раз пятерка) равно ........

Comment: Мне кто-то сказал, что это можно обойти через отключение буферизации. Но как это сделать, я не знаю. Нужно больше идей.

Comment: http://wiki.freepascal.org/gmp

Comment: кстати да, если дальше двигаться в этом направлении, GMP  - Свободная библиотека произвольной точности, имеет обширный набор оптимизированных процедур для поддержки вычислений с целыми, рациональными и вещественными числами. Режимы округления, совместимые со спецификациями IEEE-754, не поддерживаются. Имеет интерфейс языка C. Доступна на [сайте](http://gmplib.org). Разрабатываются версии и для Паскаля, [например]
(http://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/h-index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Такое подойдёт?

```
Program BigString;
Var BigString : array [1 .. 1000] of Char;
Begin
write ('Введите не более 1000 знаков: ');
readln (BigString);
write ('Знак N300 = ');
writeln (BigString[300])
End.
```

Comment: "String" -  Строковая переменная - это последовательность символов с динамической длиной, и постоянным максимальным размером в диапазоне от 1 до 255. Соответственно если надо больше, то это массивы сами создаём и сами потом обрабатываем

Comment: Не работает. Не получается ввести за один раз более 255 символов во Free Pascal. Когда начинаешь писать цифры, доходит до 255, а потом больше писать нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

тогда еще более вручную.. (стараюсь не усложнять, не кандидат в идеалы):

```
    Program BigStringEnter;
    uses crt;
    Var BigString : array [1 .. 1000] of Char;
    Var i : integer;
    Begin
        write ('Введите не более 1000 знаков: ');
        i:=0;
    repeat
        Inc(i); 
        BigString[i] := readkey;
        write(BigString[i]);
    until BigString[i] = #13;

    write ('Знак N300 = ');
    if i > 300 then writeln (BigString[300])
    else writeln ('Пусто, потому что в массиве ', i,'символов ');
    End.
```

Comment: Спасибо, алгоритм я понял, дальше сам разберусь)))